# VBA problems with finding max values and copying names to a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, max, copy-paste

I experience a lot of trouble while designing my first code in Excel VBA. The problem is as following: in column B (worksheet 1), I inserted the names of some students. in column C, I inserted the marks of the corresponding students (see table 1).

In worksheet 2 table 2, I want cells A1:A3 to display the names of the 3 best students. After watching a lot of YouTube tutorials, I still did not manage to figure out how to do it. Is there anyone who could help me designing this code in VBA?

Table 1 worksheet 1:

```
Student Mark
Alex    9,5
Sophie  7
Nick    8
Paul    4
Helena  9
jan 6
```

table 2 worksheet 2:

```
Best students
?
?
?
```

Comment: Sort by "Mark" descending, copy first 3 students... shouldn't be to hard. Here is a similar problem [Excel VBA: Sort, then Copy and Paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117339/excel-vba-sort-then-copy-and-paste)

Comment: You do not need to use VBA for this. You can use the `=LARGE()` for this. Alternatively, if you do require VBA then use the same method with `Application.WorksheetFunction()` method.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any coding for that. Just create a Pivot Table from your data (one column for student, the other one for mark), and use the "Top 10..." Filter to filter the top 3 marks. See the screenshot (unfortunately, I have only German version of Excel, but hope that the screenshot can help point you in the right direction).

[Pivot Table Screenshot (German)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEDQW.png)